# Unable to find package com.google.cast

Tags: android, google-cast

I recently updated ADT to point to Google APIs 18.  The install went fine it seems and I'm able to point my Project Properties to Google APIs 18, however, Eclipse can't find the package com.google.cast.  Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `com.google.cast` is not part of Android.

Near as I can tell, you will need to [download a ZIP file](https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/) containing their library project, import it into your IDE, mark it as actually *being* a library project, then attach that library project to your app.

Actually using those APIs appears to require a whitelisting, and it is in violation of their license to actually distribute an app (or, near as I can tell, source code) without express written permission of Google.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I thought it was part of API 18 for some reason.

Comment: Do you know a site that has explicit instructions?  I keep getting NoClassDefFoundError on CastContext as well as android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton but I clearly have both libraries included in my project.  The project builds fine as well, it just crashes with NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: It seems I need the entire mediarouter project (not just the jar) as I need the resource attributes.  But now for mediarouter to work, I need appcompat library, but that conflicts with actionbarsherlock.  The build errors never end.  Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: @clu: Android offers two `MediaRouteButton` implementations, one in `android.support.v7.app` and one in `android.app`. The latter one does not have any obvious ties to the action bar, though I may be missing something. But if the cast library absolutely requires an `AppCompat` action bar... that's just plain dumb. File a bug. You might also try commenting on Les Vogel's answer, as he's a Googler, and I'm just some guy. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use android.app as I need to support API levels lower than 16.  I've filed a bug against google-cast-sdk: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=13
Thanks for your help CommonsWare!

Comment: @clu Any luck getting past this issue?  I am in the same boat.

Answer (score 3):

CommonsWare is correct, additionally, you'll need the v18 Android Support Libraries.  v7/mediaRouter & v7/appCompat

Comment: I've filed a bug against google-cast-sdk as suggested by CommonsWare.  https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=13

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this to work for me. Originally, I tried doing it like I used ActionBarSherlock (making it a library, went to `Project -> Properties` and told it to use that library, etc) but that didn't work. Finally, I got frustrated and simply moved the `GoogleCastSdkAndroid-1.0.0.jar` file from the `lib` folder of the library directly into the `lib` folder of the project.

So, again, I imported from existing code the SDK into my workspace, then took the jar file from its library and put it directly into my project's `lib` folder. Not sure if that's how it's supposed to be, but the sample TicTacToe game is now error free and runs on my Nexus 4.

Comment: I had to do this same thing. I downloaded the API library, imported into eclipse IDE, Marked it as library, Added that to my application as a dependency and it still could not resolve it. So I ended up copying the JAR into my lib as well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to run one of the Google Cast sample apps without having installed the Google Cast SDK. The instructions for installing the SDK and all necessary support libraries were just uploaded [here on GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample/blob/master/INSTALL_CAST_ECLIPSE.txt). I'm quoting below the relevant section for installing the Cast SDK itself:

> http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res
>
> You can either add the Cast SDK as a library project in your workspace, or add
>   the GoogleCastSdkAndroid-x.x.x.jar directly to the project you're building. The
>   former is recommended if you have multiple Cast-related projects in your
>   workspace.
>
> As a library project: Follow the Support Library setup instructions linked
>   above for your downloaded and extracted SDK.
>
> As an included library:
>
> 1. Copy the /libs folder from your downloaded SDK to your Cast-related project.
> 2. In the Package Explorer window, open (your Cast project)/libs and right
>      click on GoogleCastSdkAndroid-x.x.x.jar. Select Build Path->Add to Build
>      Path.